# Getting An Undefined Method Error in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm using paperclip & Rails 4 and am getting this error when accessing my galleries index page.

Here is the error:
[image]

The code I have for the index page is this:

```
<h3> for <%= Property.name %></h3>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @galleries.property.each do |gallery| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', property_gallery_path(params[:property_id], gallery) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_property_gallery_path(params[:property_id], gallery) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', property_gallery_path(params[:property_id], gallery), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And my galleries controller page is this

```
 class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_imageable
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_gallery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /galleries
  # GET /galleries.json
  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
  end

  # GET /galleries/1
  # GET /galleries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /galleries/new
  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  # GET /galleries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /galleries
  # POST /galleries.json
  def create
    @gallery = @imageable.galleries.new(gallery_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.save

        if params[:images]
          params[:images].each { |image|
            @gallery.pictures.create(image: image)
          }
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @imageable, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /galleries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /galleries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to property_gallery_path, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /galleries/1
  # DELETE /galleries/1.json
  def destroy
    @gallery.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to galleries_url, notice: 'Gallery was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_gallery
      @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_property
      @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_imageable
      klass = [Property, Space].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"]}
      puts "Klass is #{klass.inspect}"
      @imageable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
      puts "Imageable is #{@imageable.inspect}"
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def gallery_params
      params.permit(:gallery)
    end


end
```

Now after thinking about it, I went to my Galleries controller and looked under the index line.  There, there’s a @galleries = Gallery.all, which of course is pulling all the galleries relevant to the property.  I know that it’s pulling all the galleries relevant to the property because I have the before_action :set_property and the before_action :set_gallery.

I’m wondering if the no method error has to do with how the property is being set.  I’m not sure.  But my property_id is being set as “1” in my request parameters.  So the value is passing along.

Any thing obvious I’m missing?  And and I generally thinking about this the right way?

Here's my entire galleries_controller.rb

```
    class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_imageable
  before_action :set_property, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_gallery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /galleries
  # GET /galleries.json
  def index
    @galleries = @property.galleries
  end

  # GET /galleries/1
  # GET /galleries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /galleries/new
  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  # GET /galleries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /galleries
  # POST /galleries.json
  def create
    @gallery = @imageable.galleries.new(gallery_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.save

        if params[:images]
          params[:images].each { |image|
            @gallery.pictures.create(image: image)
          }
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @imageable, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /galleries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /galleries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to property_gallery_path, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /galleries/1
  # DELETE /galleries/1.json
  def destroy
    @gallery.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to galleries_url, notice: 'Gallery was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_gallery
      @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_property
      @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_imageable
      klass = [Property, Space].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"]}
      puts "Klass is #{klass.inspect}"
      @imageable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
      puts "Imageable is #{@imageable.inspect}"
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def gallery_params
      params.permit(:gallery)
    end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all

```
   @galleries = Gallery.all
```

will return you all galleries irrespective of property

if you want to fetch galleries for any property do this

```
@galleries = @property.galleries
```

secondly you cannot fetch single property from galleries as galleries is an array which you are doing here

```
<% @galleries.property.each do |gallery| %>
```

you need to do

```
<% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
 <%property = gallery.property %>
 #what you want to do
<% end %>
```

also update your before_action

```
 before_action :set_property, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

and change this

```
def set_property
  @property = Property.find(params[:id])
end
```

to

```
def set_property
  @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
end
```

Comment: How did you come to know that a property `has_many` galleries? Just curious to know!

Comment: :) from the model names: property has some images which will be saved as gallery i guess. secondly this line in the question. 'There, there’s a @galleries = Gallery.all, which of course is pulling all the galleries relevant to the property', you see relevant shows this relation.

Comment: Thanks Athar. . .  so I made those changes, but am getting this now: "undefined method `galleries' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: you need index action to before_action for set_property.

Comment: Ok.  I set the index action, class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_imageable
  before_action :set_property, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_gallery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

but now I'm getting "Couldn't find Property with 'id'="

Comment: okay i was assuming that your index action have to show galleries for some specific property. correct if i was wrong. from where you are calling index action for gallery are you sending property_id as parameter?

Comment: I just edited my answer to show my entire galleries controller page. Does that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83686/discussion-between-athar-and-zkidd).

Answer (score 0):

`@galleries` is plural - basically an array of gallery objects, so you can't call a method directly on it. You need to iterate through each, and then call the method on the individual object.

You can achieve the similar thing in the following fashion:

```
<tbody>
  <% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', property_gallery_path(params[:property_id], gallery) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_property_gallery_path(params[:property_id], gallery) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', property_gallery_path(params[:property_id], gallery), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I just changed galleries to gallery in the controller and in the index view, and still getting the same error.